# Ansible module succeeds on my Mac, but fails on a Rock Linux box?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, paramiko

I created an Ansible module shown on this post [Pass/fail result for Paramiko SFTPClient get() and put() functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77915725/pass-fail-result-for-paramiko-sftpclient-get-and-put-functions) Here's a simple playbook to test the module.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test that my module works
      sftp:
        host: "{{ sftp_url }}"
        user: "{{ sftp_user }}"
        password: "{{ sftp_password }}"
        src: "/devops/junk.txt"
        dest: "/tmp/junk.txt"
        direction: download
      register: result
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I'm able to run it successfully on my Mac and o Ubuntu Linux. However, when I run it on a Rocky Linux box, I get

```
2024-02-01 17:42:32,518 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

2024-02-01 17:42:32,748 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
2024-02-01 17:42:32,792 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
2024-02-01 17:42:34,060 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | ok: [localhost]
2024-02-01 17:42:34,095 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | TASK [Test SFTP] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
2024-02-01 17:42:35,086 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/devops/junk.txt'
2024-02-01 17:42:35,100 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/jenkins/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1706827354.125057-1845-53715366175385/AnsiballZ_sftp.py\", line 107, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/jenkins/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1706827354.125057-1845-53715366175385/AnsiballZ_sftp.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/jenkins/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1706827354.125057-1845-53715366175385/AnsiballZ_sftp.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.sftp', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.sftp', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py\", line 225, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py\", line 97, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py\", line 87, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_sftp_payload_w5bn7ztl/ansible_sftp_payload.zip/ansible/modules/sftp.py\", line 67, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_sftp_payload_w5bn7ztl/ansible_sftp_payload.zip/ansible/modules/sftp.py\", line 62, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_sftp_payload_w5bn7ztl/ansible_sftp_payload.zip/ansible/modules/sftp.py\", line 30, in transfer_file\n  File \"/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py\", line 757, in put\n    file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/devops/junk.txt'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
2024-02-01 17:42:35,113 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
2024-02-01 17:42:35,119 p=1787 u=jenkins n=ansible | localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The file is definitely there of course. Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Any clues? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is the SAME playbook when run on my Mac.

```
$ ls /devops
ls: /devops: No such file or directory

$ ls /tmp
(shows nothing)

$ ansible-playbook sftp.yml 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Test that my module works] ******************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "meta": {
            "dest": "/tmp/junk.txt",
            "direction": "download",
            "src": "/devops/junk.txt",
            "status": "success"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

$ ls /tmp
ansible.log junk.txt
```

Comment: What is throwing this exception? Please provide the full exception trace. Also, please provide a `stat` / `find` in the same playbook, with the same delegation so we can indeed assert the file exists.

Comment: It appears to be failing on a hostname lookup (`socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`). Are your Mac and the Linux box running in the same network?

Comment: @larsks I updated my post with the correct error message

Comment: Your question has to stand alone. You cannot refer to another post for your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `sftp` module something that you wrote? In the error message, we see it failing with this `FileNotFoundError` exception:

```
      File \"/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py\", line 757, in put
        file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/devops/junk.txt'
```

It's looking for `/devops/junk.txt` on **the local machine**, but from your playbook it looks like you're trying to retrieve that file from the remote machine.

It looks like `src` and `dest` are getting mixed up, or the code isn't respecting the value of the `direction` attribute.

Comment: I updated my post to show that I run it successfully on my Mac. Yes i wrote the module, and linked it in my post.

Comment: Thanks you! This made me look at my code "... or the code isn't respecting the value of the direction attribute". I updated locally the default direction to be `download` and removed that in my playbook.  I did commit, but did NOT however pushed my changes.